# How to order observations in R for a graphic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to ask you how can I order the observations in one variable- needing it for my graphic. Now, the observations are sorted by 1 to 5 and I need to do a rank by 5,3,1,2,4
For more understanding: This is the x- axis of my graphic, I make a discrete geom_bar and need this ranging for better visualizing the data (y-axis is only count)

Thankful for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{ggplot2} will reorder numeric and character data. In order to impose an order on your data, you need to

- convert it to an *ordered factor*, and
- impose your desired order.

Luckily this is very easy in a single step using the [`reorder` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reorder.factor.html):

```
observations = reorder(1 : 5, c(5, 3, 1, 2, 4))
```

Comment: thank you...so, when I understand it right, can I use my variable name instead of the "observations" here? and then use the variable name for plotting my x axis

Comment: `ggplot(data=data,aes(x=abzufr))+geom_bar(aes(fill=abzufr))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "OrRd", name="Arbeitszufriedenheit", labels=c("progressive Zufriedenheit","stabilisierte Zufriedenheit","resignative Zufriedenheit","konstruktive Unzufriedenheit","fixierte Unzufriedenheit"))+
  theme_classic()+theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())`

Comment: this is exactly my ggplot code, the observations are in the x axis called abzufr

Comment: @AnettaS Yes, for that code you’d need to apply the `reorder` function to your `data$abzufr` column (`data$abzufr = reorder(data$abzufr, c(5, 3, 1, 2, 4))` if it’s indeed five different values).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a vector of observations - this should do the trick when "observations" is your vector of values:

```
observations <- 1:5 # example data
new_order <- observations[c(5,3,1,2,4)]
new_order 

5 3 1 2 4
```

Comment: ggplot2 will ignore this

Comment: oh okay sorry then, I did not understand that the problem was with ggplot.

Comment: thanks for your advisement, unfortunately it doesn't work.....yes, that is the problem, I used the "new_order" as the new variable instead of the old one, but now came an error...Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1394): fill, x